# Last man on earth because he died the moment something happened?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember watching a Movie years ago but can’t remember the name.

The general premise was that a scientist (I think) finds he is the only man left alive. There are no other signs of any other people anywhere. After a while he meets a female and then another male joins them and I think the female ends up leaving him for the 3rd man.

I think the film was Australian or set in Australia, it was certainly somewhere hot he spends a lot of time studying the sun.

He works out the 3 “survivors” all died at the same moment (think at least 2 of them where suicide)

While he is alone I think there is a scene where he recreates a dictators rally with cardboard cutouts or mannequins

I think it turns out an experiment of his caused whatever happened to happen and I believe he tries to recreate that including killing himself at that moment.

Any idea what the film is?

Comment: Thank you yes :) the quiet earth :)

Comment: @Machavity: He can't accept someone else's Duplicate. :) That said, since he's acknowledged it, I'll fast-track it.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Gotta love dupehammers :)